# I need to do work with HTML5. How to split div into multiple sections?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I have numeric spin button. If we change the number in spin button that many divs i need to generate.

Ex:

if it is 3, i need 3 divs where first div need not want vertical split. Second div should have two sections (ie. One split). Third div should need 3 parts.

One line should have one div. How to achieve this. Please help me

Comment: so say if your number was 5. youd have 1x1(not split), 1x1(1 split, 2 divs), 1x1(2 split, 3 divs), 1x1(3 split, 4 divs), 1x1(4 split, 5 divs). So 5 equal divs but first one is one div, second one is one div into two and so on ?

Comment: yes.. we can do with multiple divs in a single row or draw verticall line for a single div

Comment: try put a JSFiddle together so I can try give it ago with what you have

Comment: I have no idea how to do that.. can u give some suggestions to that

Comment: put your code here : http://jsfiddle.net/ : save it, then give us the URL to your saved fiddle. We can then edit it, save it then give you back an updated version :) So put the HTML, CSS and Javascript on that site :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/130z0m18/

Comment: Hi Can  you please check it from here

Comment: i already started on my own : http://jsfiddle.net/5gvv27rr/ : still editing but you can get the idea

Comment: Working Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/5gvv27rr/2/ : just change the number at the top of the Javascript

Comment: Look at my answer for the updated code that does what you asked for

Comment: Think you should accept an answer, or if its not what you wanted, tell us

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need a spinner that when increased adds rows to page where each row added is divided into cells and the number of cells in each row is equal to the number of the row itself.

So the 1st row will have 1 undivided cell, 2nd row would be divided into 2 cells, 3rd row into 3 cells,..etc.

Decreasing the spinner value should remove any rows above the current value of the spinner.

Assuming you want all the divs to be equal widths, the below will work. If you didnt want equal widths, just tweak the `CSS` :

```js
$('#spinner').change(function(){
  // get current spinner value
   var curVal = Number($(this).val());
  // get number of rows currently present
   var curCount = $('.groupRow').length;
  
   // if more rows present than the value
   // remove all rows after the value
   if(curVal<curCount){
     var newVal=curVal-1;
     $('.groupRow:gt('+newVal+')').remove();
   }
   else{
     // otherwise, add the number of elements
     // needed to equal the value
     var toAdd = curVal - curCount;
     // use this number in a loop to add this many rows
     // with each row having that same number of cells  
     for(var i=0; i<toAdd; i++){
       // start making the row...  
       var row='<div class="groupRow"><ul class="groupUl">';
         // only the first cell in the row has the class left
         // if after first run, change `left` to an empty string 
         var left = i==0 ? 'left' : '';
         var myStuff = ''; // if you have any data to add to the div, do it here
         for(var r=0; r < (curCount+1); r++){
              row += '<li class="'+left+' groupCell">'+myStuff+'</li>';
         }
       row += '</ul></div>';  // cap off the end of the row 
       // append the created row to the `mainRow`
       $('.mainRow').append(row);
        
     }
   }
});
```

```css
.mainRow {display:table;border-collapse:separate;border-spacing:5px; width:600px;}
.groupRow {display:table;border-collapse:separate;border-spacing:5px; width:600px}
.groupRow ul {display:table-row; width: 100%;}
.groupRow li.left {display: table-cell; text-align: left; width: 20px; white-space:nowrap;}
.groupRow li {display: table-cell; text-align: right; width: auto;
  background-color:#cccccc; width:25px; height:45px;border-spacing:10px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="movie">Change number of divs : </label><input id="spinner" type="number" value="1" min="1" max="30" step="1"/>
<hr>
<div class="mainRow">
  <div class="groupRow">
     <ul class="groupUl">
        <li class="left groupCell"> </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I put yours in a JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/fbvopfn8/ but Im not sure that's what he wanted. So I used your 'spinner' to help me out with mine. http://jsfiddle.net/5gvv27rr/3/

Comment: @AJ_91 yeah, hard to tell exactly what the OP needs

Comment: @Venkatsara when you say you want all rows, do you mean like this? https://jsfiddle.net/fbvopfn8/1/

Comment: read my first comment on the question, think that's what he wants

Comment: @DelightedD0D combinatiion of both i need...  first line-no split required second line- 2 sections, 3rd div - 3 sections required... and so on

Comment: @Venkatsara I believe I understand what you need now, please see my edit above and/or this jsfiidle https://jsfiddle.net/fbvopfn8/6/ let me know if that's not quite it

Answer (score 0):

i already started on my own : http://jsfiddle.net/5gvv27rr/4/ : still editing but you can get the idea.

This is with the help of the other answer from : @DelightedD0D

html

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='mainDiv'></div>

<label for="movie">Change number of divs : </label><input id="spinner" type="number" value="5" min="1" max="30" step="1"/>
```

JS

```
$('#spinner').change(function(){
var myNode = document.getElementById("mainDiv");
while (myNode.firstChild) {
    myNode.removeChild(myNode.firstChild);
}
//var spinButtonNumber = 6; //change this number 
var spinButtonNumber = Number($(this).val());
var mainDiv = document.getElementById('mainDiv');

var mainDivWidth = 600;
var mainDivHeight = 100;

mainDiv.style.width = mainDivWidth +'px';
mainDiv.style.height = mainDivHeight +'px';

var divWidth = mainDivWidth/spinButtonNumber;
var divHeight = mainDivHeight;
//console.log("main" + mainDiv.style.width);

for(i=0; i<spinButtonNumber; i++)
{
    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.id = 'div' +i;
    //var thisDiv = document.getElementById("'div' +i");
    newDiv.className = 'childDiv';
    newDiv.style.width = divWidth + 'px';
    newDiv.style.height = '50px';
    newDiv.style.left = 100;
    //console.log(newDiv.style.width);
    mainDiv.appendChild(newDiv);
    for(j=0;j<=i;j++){
        var thisDiv = document.getElementById('div' + i);
        var newDiv1 = document.createElement('div');
        var thisDivWidth = (divWidth)/(i+1);
        newDiv1.className = 'secondChildDiv';
    newDiv1.style.width = thisDivWidth + 'px';
    newDiv1.style.height = '40px';
    newDiv1.style.left = 100;
    console.log(thisDivWidth);
    thisDiv.appendChild(newDiv1);


        console.log("this" + i + " div width : " + thisDiv.style.width);
    }
}
});
```

CSS

```
    #mainDiv{

    background-color: red;
    opacity: 1;
}

.childDiv{
    background-color: white;
    float:left;


}
.secondChildDiv{
    background-color: steelblue;
    float:left;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    border: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: i know so change the number at the top of the javascript file like ive said